# Which part of Embedded toolchain generates the linker script

Tags: c, linker, embedded, toolchain, linker-scripts

Which part of the Embedded toolchain is responsible for generating the linker script?
And if it is the linker, why would the linker generate a script for itself to define the memory segments? **Aren't files like symbol table, map file,.. etc are generated by some tool to be used by some other tool that comes after it?**

Comment: The "programmer/developer" part, unless it is some default.

Comment: Most compilers would have a fixed linker script as part of the toolchain itself. You don't need to generate a new linker script for each program you link. If you directly invoke the linker, the defaults are also mostly fine.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Specifically for "Embedded", the defaults are mostly not fine.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya rather useless if we consider embedded targets.

Comment: The "defaults" might be fine only in case that you have a toolchain tailored specifically to your *board* (not only the processor), and knows your exact memory map, including off-chip flashes/ROMs, peripherals connected (not always necessary) and such. But even in that case, one might be interested to customize how the memory is being laid out depending on specific requirements.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, you are right the defaults probably won't be fine for the embedded target and in that case one should not invoke the linker directly. If you invoke it through the toolchain, the toolchain would have a pre-written linker script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker script is not automatically generated file. It can be generated by the startup code generators like STM32CubeMX.

Linker script defines how the memory is organized and it strongly depends on the hardware architecture and programmers needs.

So basically linker script has to be written by the programmer. Some manufacturers provide ready-made ones for their hardware (for example MicroChip) or software which helps generate one for your hardware.

Even having such generated by software or provided by the manufacturer is not enough as most more advanced projects require special memory layouts and the programmer has to modify them to suit his needs

Comment: When you press "Build" for your project, there is a default linker script generated with your project. Then, which part of the toolchain generated it for the linker?

Comment: @AhmedHesham When we speak of "toolchain" we usually do not include IDE in it. Yet you seem to be talking about some specific IDE. Yes, IDEs can be tailored more to the very specific hardware. For example if you buy some specific evaluation board, the vendor might provide you with the IDE with pre-configured project templates which include linker scripts for this specific board.

Comment: So, the linker needs a linker script in order to know how to create the memory segments. The linker script is a code that you as a developer write it, but an IDE writes it for you and inputs it to the linker for you just to make things easier for a developer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AhmedHesham Yes, pretty much.

Comment: I think this is similar to the startup code, which is written by a developer then provided to the linker. But an embedded IDE might generate a default startup code in order to make life easier for a developer.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, the linker script is pre-made and provided by the compiler port and/or the IDE. It is *not* generated - rather it dictates how the executable should be generated. The reason why embedded IDEs always want to know your exact part number upon starting a project is mainly to ensure that the right linker script gets added.

If you know the linker script syntax, you can also write them yourself, for a certain target. C compilers tend to want pre-defined `.data`/`.bss`/`.rodata`/`.text` etc sections to be present however, or the "C run-time" (startup library code) might not work. Similarly, the stack location is often specified by the linker script and the SP is set accordingly (by hardware or software).

Not to be confused with the map file. The linker script is *input* to the linker telling it "you should place stuff here", whereas the map file is *output* from the linker telling "this is where stuff ended up".